# Why is a SubView resizing after InterfaceRotation?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiview

I'm adding a subview to the UiView of my mainviewcontroller, that is presented in a similar way as a UIModalViewController with the Formsheet-style. (so it doesn't fill teh whole screen)

No if the device rotates the subview somehow gets resized to fill the whole mainview...
Even if I manually set:

```
subViewCtrl.view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingNone;
```

it still autoresizes.
Why can't it simple stay in the middle as any other subview would?

Comment: -1 Not enough code to solve your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out myself.

I accidentally did

```
[self.view.superview addSubview:rowCtrl.view];
```

so I changed this too

```
[self.view addSubview:rowCtrl.view];
```

and it worked as intended. Thanks anyway!
Of course, then one also has to set

```
rowCtrl.view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin;
```

otherwise it doesn't get centered properly when the interface rotates.

Answer (score 0):

Is the view resizing, or is the view staying the same size while the dimensions of the screen change?  You may want UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth and/or UIViewResizingFlexibleHeight.  If you use those values then your subview will resize to remain a constant distance from the edges of the screen; your view will change sizes, but remain centered.

Comment: Well, the point is, I don't want it to resize. I want it to just stay the same, while staying centered. As I said its currently resizing to fill the whole screen.